# How to handle php artisan routes?

Tags: php, laravel, rest, api

I´ve got a server running laravel.
If I type in the php artisan route:list command, it displays all routes as usual.

[image]

Now if I try using Postman to execute GET, POST or DELETE requests, it doesn´t work because I´m not sure what goes into the curly brackets at the end of the URI´s. Im running a REST API btw. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

It is a some sort of values that is used by controllers. It could be primitive like string or int, or an id from database that will be converted by Laravel to object and injected in your controller method.

In example, after sending GET to /users/1 (route: users/{user}), in your controller you will get an access to object User, that has an id of 1 in your database.

Take a look at route parameters in docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#route-parameters

Answer (score 0):

Any specific error it gives while accessing the route through postman.

You can specify your route as below.

`Route::get('/test/{id}', function($id){
  dd('ID is : ' . $id);
});`

Let me know if this helps..

Answer (score 0):

generally is an ID like some int or string, but you can do whatever uri you like in ur API just like web.routes.